Prove infinite sum inequality
Let $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that
$$
\sum_{k\geq m+1} \frac{1}{k^2} \leq \frac{1}{m}.
$$
Looking at the numbers, it makes sense and probably the proof is not so hard but I do not see it yet. Can someone help out?

Take a look at the area below the discrete and continuous case of $1/x^2$

\begin{equation*}
\sum_{k = m + 1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}\le\sum_{k = m + 1}^\infty\frac{1}{k(k - 1)} = \sum_{k = m + 1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{k - 1} - \frac{1}{k}\right) = \frac{1}{m}.
\end{equation*}
